# What does inptr and outptr mean

Tags: c, pointers, cs50

Does anyone know what inptr and outptr mean? I know it's short for in and out pointer, but I just can't seem to grasp the purpose of it? Also if you can tell me why FILE is in there too id appropriate it.
Thank you!

char *infile = argv[1];
    char *outfile = argv[2];

```
// open input file
FILE *inptr = fopen(infile, "r");
if (inptr == NULL)
{
    printf("Could not open %s.\n", infile);
    return 2;
}

// open output file
FILE *outptr = fopen(outfile, "w");
if (outptr == NULL)
{
    fclose(inptr);
    printf("Could not create %s.\n", outfile);
    return 3;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`inptr` corresponds to the file your program is reading from, and `outptr` corresponds to the file your program is writing to.

Most C I/O functions take a pointer to the `FILE` type, which encapsulates all the details of an I/O channel (called a *stream*) for your system (the exact structure of the `FILE` type varies from system to system, and those details are hidden from you).  `inptr` and `outptr` map to your input and output files, respectively.